# How to union a new row for every user until the last occurrence in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I want to select a new line and union it with my original table, which should double the rows. I want this addition to occur for every raw until the last occurrence as such:

Original table:

```
Name    record  Score
John-1   1      13
John-2   1      12
John-2   2      21
John-2   3      23
John-3   1      24
John-3   2      25
Matt-1   1      10
Matt-1   2      13
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT Name, record, Score
FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT Name + ‘-start’, record, 0.1
FROM Table1
```

and I am getting the following output:

```
Name        record  Score
John-1          1   13
John-1-start    1   0.1
John-2          1   12
John-2-start    1   0.1
John-2          2   21
John-2-start    2   0.1
John-2          3   23
John-2-start    3   0.1
John-3          1   24
John-3-start    1   0.1
John-3          2   25
John-3-start    2   0.1
Matt-1          1   10
Matt-1-start    1   0.1
Matt-1          2   13
Matt-1-start    2   0.1
```

This is the desired output:

```
Name        record  Score
John-1          1   13
John-1-start    1   0.1
John-2          1   12
John-2-start    1   0.1
John-2          2   21
John-2-start    2   0.1
John-2          3   23
John-2-start    3   0.1
John-3          1   24
John-3-start    1   0.1
John-3          2   25

Matt-1          1   10
Matt-1-start    1   0.1
Matt-1          2   13
```

Comment: what is the difference between current and desire output?

Comment: ???  Are you just shaving off the one copy of the last row that begins 'John%', or 'Matt%'?

Comment: John-3, record 2 and matt-1, record 2, do not have a start score because those are the last occurrences. Also, this table auto-populates with new names so I am trying to automate the process

Comment: I don't get it. The last occurrence for what? The name? Then you'd exclude John-1/1, John-2/3, John-3/2, and Matt-1/2. But you are only excluding John-3/2 and Matt-1/2. Why? Do you consider John-1, John-2, and John-3 the same person?

Comment: Perhaps for clarity change the title and text from " until the last occurrence" to "excluding the last occurrence" or  "including the last occurrence" or better yet :excluding rows with "xxx" condition whatever that condition is..describe that condition in detail, for example your comment "i need to exclude them for graphing purposes" does nothing to assist us in understanding your requirement, it could as well say "because it makes me smile" which is good but not super descriptive in contributing to understanding of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this as:

```
SELECT v.Name, v.record, v.Score
FROM Table1 t1 CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (name, record, score),
             (name + '-start', record, 0.1)
     ) v(name, record, score)
ORDER BY v.Name;
```

If you want to NULL out the final row for each name, you can do something like:

```
SELECT (case when row_number() over (partition by left(name, 4) order by name desc, record desc) > 1 then v.Name end) as Name,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by left(name, 4) order by name desc, record desc) > 1 then v.record end) as record,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by left(name, 4) order by name desc, record desc) > 1 then v.Score end) as score
FROM Table1 t1 CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (name, record, score),
             (name + '-start', record, 0.1)
     ) v(name, record, score)
ORDER BY v.Name;
```

But that type of transformation should really be done at the application level.

Comment: This is working great but it is NULL-ing out just the final raw in the entire data set. I want to NULL out the final row for every name. I want this to happen for new name that is added to the table.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a row number, then when the row number is equal to the max row number it doesn't pull that record.

Edited for update. This adds a partition by the row number of the name column left of the -, then removes the max row number of each group by joining back to the first table with the same row number partitions.

```
select name, record, score
from table1
union
select name + '-start', record, 0.1
from
    (select 
    Name,
    LEFT(Name+'-', CHARINDEX('-',Name+'-')-1) leftnamet1,
    record,
    score,
    row_number() over(partition by LEFT(Name+'-', CHARINDEX('-',Name+'-')-1) order by name, record) r
    from Table1) t1
    left join
    (select 
    leftnamet2
    max(r) maxrow
    from (select 
        LEFT(Name+'-', CHARINDEX('-',Name+'-')-1) leftnamet2,
        record,
        score,
        row_number() over(partition by LEFT(Name+'-', CHARINDEX('-',Name+'-')-1) order by name, record) r
        From Table1) t3
    group by leftnamet2
    ) t2
    on leftnamet1=leftnamet2
where r<>maxrow
```